# Converting RichTextBox to a string

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I was wondering how to convert a RichTextBox to a string. Here is my code:

```
m_rtb = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
String inputString = m_rtb.Text;
Regex regex = new Regex("\\n");
String[] thisLines = regex.Split(inputString);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
```

How can I convert my RichTextBox to a string?

Comment: What's the problem in your code above?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to get the raw unformatted text or the RTF content? They're not the same.

Comment: Surprise: The unformated text is in the RTB's Text property. Parsed into lines it is in  the Lines property

Comment: Did you have a typo in your foreach? Do you mean `foreach (string line in thisLines)` ?

Comment: is there anything special with this question or do i simply not understand it? what's the point? is `string[] lines = m_rtb.Lines;` too simple?

Answer (score -1):

You need to access the FlowDocument within the RichTextBox, find its TextPointers to the beginning and end of the document, construct a TextRange from those, and read the text from that.

Try this:

```
m_rtb = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(m_rtb.Document.ContentStart, m_rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
string text = textRange.Text;
```

Comment: The question is about a Winforms RTB!